# DefaultJmsListnerContainerFactory concurrency not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms, jmstemplate

This is my JMS configuration:

```java
@EnableJms
@Configuration
public class VmsJmsConfig implements JmsListenerConfigurer {

    @Value("${spring.activemq.broker-url}")
    String brokerUrl;
    @Value("${spring.activemq.ssl.trustStorePath}")
    String trustStorePath;
    @Value("${spring.activemq.ssl.trustStorePass}")
    String trustStorePass;

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory conFactory) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();

        defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory(conFactory);
        defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setConcurrency("10-20");
        return defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
    }

    @Bean("conFactory")
    public ConnectionFactory activeMQSslConnectionFactory() throws Exception {
        ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory activeMQSslConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);
        activeMQSslConnectionFactory.setTrustStore(trustStorePath);
        activeMQSslConnectionFactory.setTrustStorePassword(trustStorePass);

        return activeMQSslConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory handlerMethodFactory() {
        DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory factory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
        factory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter messageConverter() {
        return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureJmsListeners(JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(handlerMethodFactory());
    }
}
```

My app is listening to an ActiveMQ queue. It consumes a message, transforms it, sends a downstream request, waits for the response, and sends that response to another queue.

I want it to consume multiple messages at the same time and process them in parallel, but no matter how many consumer I set in `setConcurrency()` it only consumes 1 message at a time, and there are more than 1000 messages pending in queue.

I tried changing the `concurency`, but no luck. But when I comment downstream call, it consumes 10-20 messages at a time, I couldn't find reason for that.

Comment: Have you tried setting the [`prefetchPolicy`](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html) on your `ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory` instance? The default queue prefetch is `1000`. Try setting this to `0` instead. You can do this via your connection URL or programmatically directly on the `ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory` instance.

Comment: Yes I tried setting it to 0 and 1 as well, still same result